# How to copy 2d array of objects?

Tags: javascript

the objects still changing their value,if something that i losing can you give me an article or the documentation about that, for example:

```
const array = [
  [
    { local: '5', visit: '6' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '6', visit: '1' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '8', visit: '6' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '6', visit: '2' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '3', visit: '6' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '6', visit: '7' },
  ],
  [
    { local: '4', visit: '6' },
  ]
];
```

i tried with:

```
array.map(element => element.slice());
```

Comment: `Array.slice()` makes a shallow copy of the array (i.e. it's items are references to original objects)

Comment: hmmm i get it, ty.

Answer (score 1):

```
let copied_array = [...array];
```

Answer (score 1):

To clone an array with objects inside property, you need to perform a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript). Probably simplest with:

```
const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
const copy = array.map((row) => row.slice().map((object2Copy) => Object.assign({}, object2Copy)));
```